# CXF interceptors not being called in correct order

Tags: java, cxf

I have 4 cxf interceptors, each of which extend AbstractPhaseInterceptor. I am ordering them in the following way :

Class A:

```
public class AInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {


    public AuthenticationInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
        super.addAfter(OInInterceptor.class.getName());
        super.addAfter(HInterceptor.class.getName());

    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        System.out.println("Into AInterceptor");
        System.out.println(super.getAfter()); //This is what prints the last line.
    }
}
```

Class H:

```
 public class HInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {


    public HInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
        super.addBefore(PInterceptor.class.getName());
    }


    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        System.out.println("Into HInterceptor ...");
    }
}
```

Class O:

```
 public class OInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private ServerPolicyEvaluator serverPolicyEvaluator;

    public OrderZeroPolicyInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
        super.addBefore(PInterceptor.class.getName());
        super.addAfter(HInterceptor.class.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        System.out.println("Into OInterceptor ...");
    }
}
```

Class P:

```
public class PInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {


    public PInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
        super.addAfter(HInterceptor.class.getName());
    }


    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        System.out.println("Into PInterceptor ...");
    }
}
```

However when I run the application I get the following output:
Into HInterceptor ...
Into AInterceptor
[com.xyz.interceptors.H, com.xyz.interceptors.O]

OInterceptor should have been executed before AInterceptor. Why are the interceptors being executed in the incorrect order ?